# Can I set value of an outgoing bazel transition based on properties of the dep?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp

I would like to propagate a custom build setting from a set of bazel targets to some of their transitive dependencies. In other words, I would like a target to say "use X variant of Y library", and that setting gets propagated down to the target(s) in Y library where that setting is consumed.

My naive implementation just adds an outgoing transition at the top-level target where I want to set the setting. However, I would like to contain the non-default setting value to the targets between the ones that set it and the ones that consume it. This should avoid the setting "polluting" all downstream deps and forcing re-build of other deps which don't consume the library. This problem is described [here](https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/MNdLiMP5yAQ/m/nxmbrartBQAJ).

My thought is I could wrap `cc_library` with a macro. The macro would know how to inject the build setting and will only forward the setting to its deps which are declared as the same macro:

```
custom_cc_library(
    name="top_level",
    custom_setting="non_default_value",
    deps=[
        ":middle_level",  # custom_setting is set to "non_default_value" for this dep
        ":lib_which_doesnt_consume_setting",  # custom_setting is set to the default value for this dep
    ],
    ...
)

custom_cc_library(
    name="middle_level",
    deps=[
        ":setting_consumer",  # setting is set to "non_default_value" for this dep
    ],
    ...
)

cc_library(
    name="lib_which_doesnt_consume_setting",
    ...
)

setting_consumer(
    name="setting_consumer",
    ...
)
```

However, outgoing transitions are configured per rule attribute, so I can't see a way to specify that some deps of `custom_cc_library` should receive a different version of the build setting than others (given that I can't modify the implementation of `cc_library`). It seems the best I can do is add a separate `custom_deps` attribute to `custom_cc_library` which I pass the new setting to.  This is doable, just less ergonomic.

Is there any way to apply different values of an outgoing transition per dep? And/or am I suffering from the X/Y problem and there's a better way to select library versions from targets in bazel?